# Pub/Sub publishing to topic within in a Cloud Function yields google.auth.exceptions.TransportError or requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I recently started receiving the following error when publishing to a Pub/Sub when invoked within a Cloud Function (note I cannot replicate this error locally):

```
> AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x3e533b442910>" raised exception!
> ...
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

I have not changed anything in the way I publish topics and am [following the Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher):

```
message_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=params_bytes)
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

---

Here are some **additional logs**:

[image]

Comment: Are you hitting this error every time or is it transient? In the second case I feel that this may happen due to some pub/sub quota exhaustion. Otherwise please share a simplified reproducible example. Also check if you are using latest library versions.

Answer (score 0):

can you try future.result() instead of any callbacks you added in case?
Let me know how it goes it actually fixed the issue. Again, it might make the pipeline synchronous.